# how to add multiple PDF within docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a developer account with docusign and able to upload a single PDF and sign that so. But as per my requirement I need to upload multiple PDF file within docusign at one go and sign them accordingly. We are currently using docusign SOAP API and here is the sample access URL: http://etplprojects.net/docusign_api/soap/ Is that possible? Please suggest.

Comment: Please show your current request so we can see what you're missing.

Comment: REQUIREMENT: Please clarify: Do you want multiple documents in one envelope, each with a signature, or multiple envelopes created, one per document with a signature, but be able to upload many at once aka a Bulk upload to get signatures

Comment: Also for quick reference on REST with multiple documents in a envelope here is a link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223946/docusign-api-composite-templates-no-response

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of Create Envelope from Composite Templates and Forms SOAP Method: 1 envelope with multiple documents from server Templates, but you can add the documents node to inline templates and include them there and not even use a server template, but performance is better if you have the template already on the server with the static PDF bytes, roles (recipients) and tabs and then use the Document NODE (not plural) to replace the server template pdf bytes with the one specified in the Document NODE.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <soap:Header>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
            <ns:EnvelopeInformation>
                <ns:AccountId>your account guid goes here</ns:AccountId>
                <ns:EmailBlurb>Your Email message</ns:EmailBlurb>
                <ns:Subject>Your Email subject</ns:Subject>
                <ns:Notification />
            </ns:EnvelopeInformation>
            <ns:CompositeTemplates>
                <ns:CompositeTemplate>
                    <ns:ServerTemplates>
                        <ns:ServerTemplate>
                            <ns:Sequence>1</ns:Sequence>
                            <ns:TemplateID>Your server template guid goes here
                            </ns:TemplateID>
                        </ns:ServerTemplate>
                    </ns:ServerTemplates>
                    <ns:InlineTemplates>
                        <ns:InlineTemplate>
                            <ns:Sequence>1</ns:Sequence>
                            <ns:Envelope>
                                <ns:AccountId>your account guid goes here</ns:AccountId>
                                <ns:Recipients>
                                    <ns:Recipient>
                                        <ns:ID>1</ns:ID>
                                        <ns:UserName>client Admin</ns:UserName>
                                        <ns:Email>youremail@gmail.com@gmail.com</ns:Email>
                                        <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:RoutingOrder>1</ns:RoutingOrder>
                                        <ns:RoleName>AE</ns:RoleName>
                                    </ns:Recipient>
                                    <ns:Recipient>
                                        <ns:ID>2</ns:ID>
                                        <ns:UserName>your Name</ns:UserName>
                                        <ns:Email>youremail@gmail.com@gmail.com</ns:Email>
                                        <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:RoutingOrder>2</ns:RoutingOrder>
                                        <ns:RoleName>Advertiser</ns:RoleName>
                                    </ns:Recipient>
                                </ns:Recipients>
                                <ns:Tabs />
                            </ns:Envelope>
                        </ns:InlineTemplate>
                    </ns:InlineTemplates>
                </ns:CompositeTemplate>
                <ns:CompositeTemplate>
                    <ns:ServerTemplates>
                        <ns:ServerTemplate>
                            <ns:Sequence>2</ns:Sequence>
                            <ns:TemplateID>your server template guid goes here
                            </ns:TemplateID>
                        </ns:ServerTemplate>
                    </ns:ServerTemplates>
                    <ns:InlineTemplates>
                        <ns:InlineTemplate>
                            <ns:Sequence>1</ns:Sequence>
                            <ns:Envelope>
                                <ns:AccountId>Your Account Guid goes here</ns:AccountId>
                                <ns:Recipients>
                                    <ns:Recipient>
                                        <ns:ID>1</ns:ID>
                                        <ns:UserName>client Admin</ns:UserName>
                                        <ns:Email>youremail@gmail.com</ns:Email>
                                        <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:RoutingOrder>1</ns:RoutingOrder>
                                        <ns:RoleName>AE</ns:RoleName>
                                    </ns:Recipient>
                                    <ns:Recipient>
                                        <ns:ID>2</ns:ID>
                                        <ns:UserName>David Grigsby</ns:UserName>
                                        <ns:Email>youremail@gmail.com</ns:Email>
                                        <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:RoutingOrder>2</ns:RoutingOrder>
                                        <ns:RoleName>Advertiser</ns:RoleName>
                                    </ns:Recipient>
                                </ns:Recipients>
                                <ns:Tabs>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>98</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>118</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser Advertiser Name</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>GM</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>120</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>139</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser Advertiser Name</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>GM</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>438</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>78</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser AE/Owner</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>client Admin</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>116</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>163</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser Address 1</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>123 Main Desolate road</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>60</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>185</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser City</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>Detroit</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>87</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>207</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser Main Phone</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>888-111-5555</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>103</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>228</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Contact Email Address</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>youremail@gmail.com</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>210</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>185</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser State</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>MI</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>306</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>184</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser Zip/Postal Code</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>34098</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                    <ns:Tab>
                                        <ns:DocumentID>1</ns:DocumentID>
                                        <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                                        <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                                        <ns:XPosition>240</ns:XPosition>
                                        <ns:YPosition>207</ns:YPosition>
                                        <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                                        <ns:TabLabel>Advertiser Fax</ns:TabLabel>
                                        <ns:Value>555-111-5554</ns:Value>
                                    </ns:Tab>
                                </ns:Tabs>
                            </ns:Envelope>
                        </ns:InlineTemplate>
                    </ns:InlineTemplates>
                </ns:CompositeTemplate>
            </ns:CompositeTemplates>
            <ns:ActivateEnvelope>true</ns:ActivateEnvelope>
        </ns:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```